# I am new to econometrics and don't know how to properly 'calibrate' my data set to provide the most accurate results

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am very new to econometrics and am working on a project observing the effects of GDP per capita, unemployment rates, and median household income on the homicide rate per 100,000 people. This data is cross-sectional for all 50 states in 2019.

The purpose of this project isn't necessarily to gather the 'best' data or have the most accurate results but rather to deeply analyze and understand the data. I won't be changing my original data sets but that being said, I would like to optimize my data as much as possible. There seems to be some heteroskedasticity in a few of my variables which I can correct for reasonably well but beyond that I am not sure even where to start as far as tests to run on cross-section data that can help with serial correlation, multicollinearity, and other issues it may have.

All I would really appreciate is to be guided to some tests that I can run on my data that would alert me to possible areas for improvement in how my data is used for my linear regression model.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look for correlation between your independent variables; without looking at the data, it might be high between median household income and GDP per capita.  If so, the coefficients (including signs) for an ordinary linear regression might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you could start by testing if your data follows the linearity assumption. You can do that by plotting the true y vs your predictions (or by plotting the residual vs your prediction).

Another thing you could do, is checking for outliers. You could just try to plot the features, but this might be too time-consuming if you have many features. You could plot true y vs prediction and see which observations are far away from the regression line (of course here you would make a prediction for your whole data set, not just for the testing set like in machine learning). Depending on the software you use, there is probably also a way to extract which observations have the strongest impact on your fitted line for each feature.

To spot multicollinearity you can calculate variance inflation factor (VIF) between features. If you are using R or python there should be easy implementations to find the VIF between your features. If the VIF is higher than 10, you might have a problem with your coefficients. But remember, multicollinearity is not impacting your prediction, it rather introduces some bias in your coefficients, because it becomes very hard to isolate the effect of the single features.

With features you normally build interaction features or polynomials (if you assume some non-linear relationship) to generate more possible options for the model to learn some connections between your features and your target.

To summarize: Test if conditions for linear regression are fulfilled, plot as much as possible to get an understanding of your data. And once you understand the data try to build more features from the existing ones. On top of that you might try to remove outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!